# I want to filter results by a column created in the SELECT clause

Tags: sql

There's two main tables that I'm trying to query, Client and Assessment, and then 5 secondary tables that I also need to get information from, AssessFinancialSummary, AssessHUDProgram, AssessHUDUniversal, AssessHealthInsurance, and Outcome. Basically I want to end up with a list of the most recent assessment of each type for a given client.

The Client table is linked to the Assessment table with a client ID (aka EntityID), and the Assessment table is linked to all the secondary assessment tables with an AssessmentID.
The Assessment table doesn't explicitly say what type of assessment each record is, so I have the CASE statement in the SELECT clause of the query that creates a column that has that information.

```
DECLARE @ClientID INT

SET @ClientID = 56530

SELECT C.EntityID, C.FirstName, C.LastName, A.AssessmentID, A.BeginAssessment,

       --Create a column that specifies what type of assessment each row is
       CASE
        WHEN AFS.AssessmentID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Financial Assessment'
        WHEN AHP.AssessmentID IS NOT NULL THEN 'HUD Program Assessment'
        WHEN AHI.AssessmentID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Health Insurance Assessment'
        WHEN AHU.AssessmentID IS NOT NULL THEN 'HUD Universal Assessment'
        WHEN OM.ContextID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Outcome Matrix'
       END AS AssessType,

       --Creates a column that puts each type of assessment in chronologial order (1 being the newest)
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CASE
        WHEN AFS.AssessmentID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Financial Assessment'
        WHEN AHP.AssessmentID IS NOT NULL THEN 'HUD Program Assessment'
        WHEN AHI.AssessmentID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Health Insurance Assessment'
        WHEN AHU.AssessmentID IS NOT NULL THEN 'HUD Universal Assessment'
        WHEN OM.ContextID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Outcome Matrix'
       END
               ORDER BY A.BeginAssessment DESC
               ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS AssessOrder

FROM Client AS C

INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Assessment A WHERE A.ClientID = @ClientID) AS A
ON C.EntityID = A.ClientID

LEFT OUTER JOIN AssessFinancialSummary AS AFS
ON A.AssessmentID = AFS.AssessmentID

--I omitted the other outer joins, but they follow the exact same format as the one above

WHERE C.EntityID = @ClientID
```

Right now the query returns all the assessments and ranks them chronologically by type, but I want to only return the newest assessment of each type. I tried adding "WHERE AssessOrder = 1" to the end, but I get the error "Invalid column name 'AssessOrder'."

I kinda get why this doesn't work, i.e. the SELECT clause is compiled last, so AssessOrder doesn't exist when the compiler first sees it. Is there another way to do this?

I want at most one result from each of the secondary assessment tables, and ideally it would only be the one with the most recent date.

Comment: Use a subquery, CTE, or lateral join to define the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to return the most recent item from two groupings (*assessment type* and *client*), consider `ROW_NUMBER()` for your window function with two `PARTITION BY` groupings in the form:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AssessmentType_Indicator, Client_Indicator 
                  ORDER BY Date_Field DESC)
```

Additionally, since you need to filter on this calculated field and include it in final output as a column, it should be handled in some type of nested subquery or other resultset such as [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Consider also the adjusted `ON` clause and removal of redundant `WHERE`.

```
WITH cte AS 
   (SELECT C.EntityID, C.FirstName, C.LastName, A.AssessmentID, A.BeginAssessment,
           CASE
              WHEN AFS.AssessmentID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Financial Assessment'
              WHEN AHP.AssessmentID IS NOT NULL THEN 'HUD Program Assessment'
              WHEN AHI.AssessmentID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Health Insurance Assessment'
              WHEN AHU.AssessmentID IS NOT NULL THEN 'HUD Universal Assessment'
              WHEN OM.ContextID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Outcome Matrix'
           END AS AssessType,

           -- NEW WINDOW FUNCTION WITH TWO PARTITION BY COLUMNS
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                 PARTITION BY CASE
                                 WHEN AFS.AssessmentID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Financial Assessment'                          
                                 WHEN AHP.AssessmentID IS NOT NULL THEN 'HUD Program Assessment'
                                 WHEN AHI.AssessmentID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Health Insurance Assessment'
                                 WHEN AHU.AssessmentID IS NOT NULL THEN 'HUD Universal Assessment'
                                 WHEN OM.ContextID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Outcome Matrix'
                              END,
                              A.ClientID
                 ORDER BY A.BeginAssessment DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
           ) AS AssessOrder

    FROM Client AS C

    INNER JOIN Assessment A 
        ON C.EntityID = A.ClientID AND A.ClientID = @ClientID

    LEFT OUTER JOIN AssessFinancialSummary AS AFS
        ON A.AssessmentID = AFS.AssessmentID

    -- ... OTHER JOINS (BUT LEAVE OUT REDUNDANT WHERE)
   )

SELECT EntityID, FirstName, LastName, 
       AssessmentID, BeginAssessment, AssessType
FROM cte 
WHERE AssessOrder = 1
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, Thank you! I'm going to read up more on CTEs now.

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help! Happy coding!